# How can we append CFLAGS when doing ./configure

Tags: configure

I got a configure script file that originally will create some `CFLAGS` when doing `./configure`. I am wondering how can we append some other `CFLAGS` when doing `./configure` without changing the original `CFLAGS` like:

```
./configure CFLAGS+="some flags"
```

Above is not the correct way to append so I am wondering what would be the best way to append.

Comment: `./configure CFLAGS="your flags"` should do the right thing, adding any flags `./configure` determines to be necessary. Could you try that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put multiple -I, -L and -l flags in ./configure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669463/how-to-put-multiple-i-l-and-l-flags-in-configure) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149359/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-add-cflags-and-ldflags-to-configure